# Fragment of viewpager refreshes but not supposed to

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with 4 fragments.
When I'm on the 4th fragment and I come back on the 3th one by swipe, physically, it shows the 3th but the 2nd one refreshes causing a NullPointerException because I'm not on that fragment.

When I do exactly the same thing with from the 3th to the 2nd and from the 2nd to the 1st, its works perfectly.

Does someone faced such issue before ?

Answer (score 0):

When using `ViewPager`, it will, by default, load items one before and one after the current item. You can change this behavior with [`setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks for answer. As the fragments are already created, why are they refreshed when I'm just coming back on them ?

Comment: @HubertSolecki I'm not 100% sure how Android handles this, my guess might be that the fragments are deconstructed when you scroll too far, to save memory? Have you checked to see if `onCreate` is being called when you swipe back? That could be one explanation.

Comment: Depends on what adapter you are using for the viewpager. FragmentPagerAdapter keeps all in memory while the FragmentStatePagerAdapter does not.